# Upload a PDF file through Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, file-upload

I'm trying to piece together a library-like intranet website with silverlight. Is it possible to upload a pdf file from the client PC to the server?

Also, I'd like to show the first page of the pdf file.. can I open the file on the server, take a snapshot of the title page and save it as a jpg/png thumbnail? How about get other information such as page count?

Or do I have to rely on third-party software to do this for me? (meaning, SL can't do these tasks by itself)

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files from client PCs to the server using Silverlight. If you want to display the thumbnail of the first page, then you will need to open this using a third party control. Silverlight has no native support for manipulating PDF files.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to upload a file in silverlight, though you'll need some sort of 3rd party library to support opening/reading pdf files server side.